# Why was my question voted down and blocked?

Tags: discussion

Today I posted the below question to Stack Exchange. Since I knew this site has high standards I looked up the answer on the web for an hour and searched EE Stack Exchange to be sure no one else had asked the question, so I thought it was safe.  But within 5 minutes I got four negative votes and within an hour the question was blocked. Should I try to reword the question or is it inherently inappropriate?

[Unmanaged Ethernet switch silicon?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/122667/unmanaged-ethernet-switch-silicon)

Answer (score 4):

Your question was closed because it is a shopping questions, and shopping questions are off topic here.  Read the rules.

Comment: Thanks, I not mean for it to be a shopping question. Would this version be acceptable?
“What is the simplest way to implement a three port Ethernet switch on a custom PCB? Simple means: low component count, low pin count components, little or no required programming.”

Comment: @BenYL unfortunately, that would fall on the wrong side of the shopping question line.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand why. No single chip (I'm almost certain now) does this, so I'm really looking a circuit or a circuit/firmware solution, and these are certainly in the scope of this forum. Olin, can you comment?

Comment: @BenYL A better way to ask about this might be to find a couple of applicable methods of implementing what you want, and asking "Which would be better in terms of cost and parts count, X or Y?" It's much easier to provide answers that show the pros and cons of different products or designs. Otherwise you're asking for volunteers to hunt down parts, prices, datasheets and schematics, all of which are moderately opinion-based and subject to become totally invalid as parts and prices change constantly.